# Why does the doc do not use `this` i.e `Service` for the argument for `Context` in the documentation?

Tags: android, android-service, android-context, android-syncadapter

What is the usefulness of having `Service` inherit from `Context` if it does not use it?

For example from the [android docs for sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter#java)
we see:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
    // Storage for an instance of the sync adapter
    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;   

    // etc  

    sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
```

So it does not pass `this` in the constructor for `SyncAdapter` but `getApplicationContext`.
So why is not `this` passed as `Context` in the docs? What is the point of having `Service` inherit from `Context` then?

Comment: They are both context's, but they are not the same context. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579826/is-there-a-difference-between-service-context-and-application-context-in-android). They have different lifetimes. Did you try using `this` instead?

Comment: @TylerV: No I did not try the example directly, but I can't find anywhere in the doc specifying a specific type of Context to pass in the constructor. It is odd that from an instance of `Context` we pass another type of `Context` but there is no mention of expectations. Perhaps I am not reading the docs right or I am ignorant of some convention in the docs?

Comment: `SyncAdapter` class (or its superclass) keeps a reference of the context and `sSyncAdapter` is static variable (initialized only once, single instance). So here comes the battle - current context vs. global application context

Comment: Broadly speaking, you pass ``Context``s around because different components and functions need access to contextual stuff they provide (like access to the environment the code is running in). You don't necessarily know what's being done with that context reference when you pass it. An ``Activity`` is a ``Context``, but it's also an ``Activity``, and you don't want to be passing those around to things that might hold onto them and keep them alive. So generally speaking, it's a good idea to pull the `applicationContext` and pass that instead, because it's safe for things in the app to hold on to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why is not this passed as Context in the docs?

Because the `SyncAdapter` instance is being held in a `static` field:

```java
private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
```

A `static` field is an intentional memory leak: whatever you hold in that field cannot be garbage-collected, and the same is true for anything that is referenced by that object.

`getApplicationContext()` returns the `Application` object. This is a singleton, set up when your process is forked. As such, it is "pre-leaked" — you cannot leak it further by having a `static` reference to it.

Since the `SyncAdapter` instance is being held in a `static` field, whatever `Context` we pass to the `SyncAdapter` constructor may be leaked — whether it will or not is tied to the implementation of `SyncAdapter`, which may vary by OS version or manufacturer meddling. So, to be safe, the documentation uses the `Application` singleton for the `Context`, rather than risk leaking the `SyncService` instance.

> So why is not this passed as Context in the docs?

Because that might leak the `SyncService` instance by means of the `sSyncAdapter` field.

Comment: Ah makes sense, I see! If the field was not declared as static, would passing `this` be safe?

Comment: @Jim: Probably yes. It is entirely possible that `SyncAdapter` internally could do something unfortunate that would cause a memory leak with `SyncService` instead of `Application`, but that is unlikely.